# Debian 10 - installation virtual package

Tags: debian

I am solving problem with installation virtual package. Here is dockerfile for demonstate my problem. Image is based on Debian 10

```
FROM php:7.4.4-apache-stretch

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install wget lsb-release -y
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https  ca-certificates curl
RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/>
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) ma>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install php7.4-cgi -y
```

I found out php7.4-cgi is virtual package

```
root@3004fd5ee36a:/var/www/html# apt search php7.4-cgi
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php7.4-cgi/unknown 7.4.4-1+0~20200320.15+debian10~1.gbpf8dc20 amd64
  (none)

php7.4-cgi-dbgsym/unknown 7.4.4-1+0~20200320.15+debian10~1.gbpf8dc20 amd64
  (none)



root@3004fd5ee36a:/var/www/html# apt show php7.4-cgi
Package: php7.4-cgi
State: not a real package (virtual)
N: Can't select candidate version from package php7.4-cgi as it has no candidate
N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
N: No packages found
```

It is some way to install php7.4-cgi?

Answer (score 0):

When you search for your packet in [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php7.4-cgi) then you can see, that  packet is for *Debain testing*.

I recommend you to upgrade to *bullseye*, then you can install it normaly.

Comment: This package is available for debian 10 from Sury repository.